# Enforcing values supplied are changed

Tags: jquery

Within my web app, I allow the user to create a record stored in a temporary table via an iframe and then allow them to clone/copy the same record just created but with three fields within the cloned record substituted with dummy values, that need to be changed.

Just to elaborate further, let's say that initially the user creates the following record:

```
record 1: F1:A F2:B F3:C F4: System One F5: Active
```

User can then clone record 1, which would then be created as follows:

```
record 2: F1:A_COPY F2:B_COPY F3:C_COPY F4: System One F5: Active
```

So based on record 2, the cloned record, I now need to ensure and enforce that the user has to change the first three fields that contain the string "_COPY" to actual values.

Now, with jQuery, what is the best way to ensure that these three fields within the web app are actually changed, i.e. mandatory?

Comment: Question is not very clear please add details

Comment: @Roshan - pls see additional infomration in my post above.

Answer (score 0):

We need a bit more information to be honest. When do you want to make sure they're changed?

Here is a link to something I threw together which might help you:

http://jsfiddle.net/tclayson/GaXD4/

In that I'm just cycling through each of the input elements in the form when its submitted and seeing if the value is the same or different.

You could also change the `find('...')` bit to select the specific classes of each of the input elements, and instead of alerting you can change the css or something similar to point out they need to change the value.

Hope this helps, if not then let me know a bit more about the situation and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: pls see additional infomration in my post above and thanks for your answer. Based on your answer above, how can I now search for each of these "_COPY" strings and ensure that they are changed?

Comment: you can use `indexOf` to see if the string `_copy` is in the field at all... if that's what you're asking. See: http://jsfiddle.net/tclayson/cCWNE/